# Does JDK 1.8 support Cipher suites with Diffie-Hellman (DH) keys of size 4096 bits

Tags: ssl, java-8, apache-httpclient-4.x, diffie-hellman

I want to know if *JDK 1.8* supports DH key length of 4096 bits.

Everywhere I searched, I found that `jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize` can accept only *between 1024 and 2048 bits*.

I have to connect to a site which supports

> "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)   DH 4096 bits (p: 512, g:
> 1, Ys: 512)".

But I am getting

"Could not generate DH keypair" Exception.

EDIT:

Adding a bit additional info,

I am using Apache httpclient-4.2.5 for connecting to the site.
The server also supports

> "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f) - 4096 bits".

When I use JDK 1.8 and try to connect the cipher suite is getting selected by the Server but JDK 1.8 is supporting only 2048 bits and my connection is failing.

EDIT:

Bouncy castle can be used as a workaround to support 4096 bits.
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6521495

Comment: Not sure it this is really necessary in this case. But when using cryptography which extra large keys it is usually a good idea to install the Unlimited Strength Java Cryptography Extension Policy Files into the JRE.

Comment: Thanks @Robert! I have installed Unlimited Strength JCE too, still getting the same error. Could you please elaborate on why it is not necessary so that I can find out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it works on Windows and OS X, but not on Linux. Don't ask why, all I know is Windows and OS X clients can connect via Java to servers with 4096 key size while Linux clients can't.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1163501

It's not even fixed in Fedora yet, so it may take quite a while before it makes it into CentOS/RHEL.